# Delete some files using batch files

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I must create batch file to delete files of a directory which names first symbols are "a". How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're using Windows** try this (assuming *full_path* is directory you want to delete in):

```
@echo off
DEL /Q full_path\a*.*
```

or if you want to delete files from that dir and in its subdir, try this:

```
@echo ff
DEL /Q /S full_path\a*.*
```

**If you're using Linux** (or similar), try this:

```
rm -f full_path/a*
```

or

```
rm -rf full_path/a*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like Linux or OSX or Cygwin try

```
find . -name "a*" -delete
```

If you want to remove whole directories

```
find . -name  "a*" | xargs -n 5 rm -r
```